# OnScanCompleted uri is null

Tags: android

I have an .m3u playlist that I am trying to add to android's media library. However the callback method has null uri. The code is for API-19 KitKat and above.

```
   String[] mediaFiles = newPlaylists.toArray(new String[newPlaylists.size()]);
   MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(this.c,mediaFiles, null,this);
```

The onScanCompleted is like this;

```
 public void onScanCompleted(String path, Uri uri) {
            //uri is null
    Log.d("SCAN_COMPLETED", String.format("%s is %s", path,uri));

}
```

The playlist looks like this - The playlist is ascii and not UTF-8. The songs are stored relative to the playlist location.

```
#EXTM3U
./Beyonce/(www.GRIZZLIS.lt)/Best Thing I Never Had (www.GRIZZLIS.lt).mp3
./Adele/(www.GRIZZLIS.lt)/Set Fire To The Rain (www.GRIZZLIS.lt).mp3
./Adele/(www.GRIZZLIS.lt)/Someone Like You (www.GRIZZLIS.lt).mp3
```

What's wrong with the code or playlist that could cause it to fail to add in the android media library ?

Comment: That means that the scan failed. Are you sure that the `scanFile` code is correct?

Comment: use try& catch and test it